# Caching Htttp requests responce

Tags: android, caching

I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading and caching images in my app.
Its work great then i decide to implement this for other requests from web. 
my question is how can i cache data (Like json and xml) received  from web in android ?
I mean at first request to web if request is successful response save in user device memory till he/she click update data to get fresh data and cache the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write you own `CacheManger` ,below is what Cache Manager should do :

- Hit http request and get json data
- Add data to local database first[cache the url and json data both]
- Provide Data model to your api
- When the next reuest comes to cache manager check for url first if
  present in db, provide that data since it is been already cached
- if the url as key in db is not present then only hit the http apis.